# Terraform aws_lb_ssl_negotiation_policy using AWS Predefined SSL Security Policies

Tags: terraform

According to: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_ssl_negotiation_policy.html

You can create a new resource in order to have a ELB SSL Policy so you can customized any Protocol and Ciphers you want. However, I am looking to use Predefined Security Policies set by Amazon as
`TLS-1-1-2017-01` or `TLS-1-2-2017-01`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-policy-table.html

Is there a way to use predefined policies instead of set a new custom policy?

Comment: It seems like so far it is not possible. An issue has been opened on github for further references: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1669

Answer (score 4):

Looking to solve the same problem, I came across this snippet here: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/822#issuecomment-311448488

Basically, you need to create two resources, the `aws_load_balancer_policy`, and the `aws_load_balancer_listener_policy`.  In the `aws_load_balancer_policy` you set the `policy_attribute` to reference the Predefined Security Policy, and then set your listener policy to reference that aws_load_balancer_policy.

I've added a [Pull Request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/8080) to the terraform AWS docs to make this more explicit here, but here's an example snippet:

```
resource "aws_load_balancer_policy" "listener_policy-tls-1-1" {
  load_balancer_name = "${aws_elb.elb.name}"
  policy_name        = "elb-tls-1-1"
  policy_type_name   = "SSLNegotiationPolicyType"

  policy_attribute {
    name  = "Reference-Security-Policy"
    value = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-1-2017-01"
  }
}

resource "aws_load_balancer_listener_policy" "ssl_policy" {
  load_balancer_name = "${aws_elb.elb.name}"
  load_balancer_port = 443

  policy_names = [
    "${aws_load_balancer_policy.listener_policy-tls-1-1.policy_name}",
  ]
}
```

At first glance it appears that this is creating a custom policy that is based off of the predefined security policy, but when you look at what's created in the AWS console you'll see that it's actually just selected the appropriate Predefined Security Policy.

[image: ELB Security Policy Selection]

Comment: Great answer, thanks for updating the docs too! I just wanted to note that you can also do it with one resource using aws_lb_ssl_negotatiation_policy -- see my answer for the formatted code (looks like you can't post code snippets in a comment)

Answer (score 4):

To piggy back on Kirkland's answer, for posterity, you can do the same thing with `aws_lb_ssl_negotation_policy` if you don't need any other policy types:

```
resource "aws_lb_ssl_negotiation_policy" "my-elb-ssl-policy" {
  name          = "my-elb-ssl-policy"
  load_balancer = "${aws_elb.my-elb.id}"
  lb_port       = 443

  attribute {
    name  = "Reference-Security-Policy"
    value = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define it. And the default Security Policy `ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08` has covered all ssl protocols you asked for.

Secondly, `Protocol-TLSv1.2` covers both policies (TLS-1-1-2017-01 or TLS-1-2-2017-01) you asked for as well.

(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-policy-table.html)

[image]

So make sure you enable it with below codes:

```
resource "aws_lb_ssl_negotiation_policy" "foo" {
  ...
  attribute {
    name  = "Protocol-TLSv1.2"
    value = "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm also looking for the same, but your answer doesn't really look like the answer he is looking for. You don't explain how to apply the policy and he's not looking to enable a Protocol/Cipher/Option but to apply a predefined policy.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken in my understanding, but your example applies the protocol Protocol-TLSv1.2, not a predefined policy

Comment: The form I pasted tells you which policies belong to.

Comment: It seems like so far it is not possible. An issue has been opened on github for further references: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1669